# Should I use a subquery in this situation?

Tags: sql, hive

I'm using Apache Hive and I have a query like this:

```
SELECT CASE type WHEN 'a' THEN 'A'
                 WHEN 'b' THEN 'B'
                 ELSE 'C'
            END AS map_type
       ,COUNT(user_id) AS count
FROM user_types
GROUP BY CASE type WHEN 'a' THEN 'A'
                 WHEN 'b' THEN 'B'
                 ELSE 'C'
            END
;
```

As you can see, I need to group the result by the `map_type` field, which is calculated in a complex way. In my case, will the `CASE WHEN` parts in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` be calculated twice? And if I used a subquery like below, will it be more efficient or not?

```
SELECT map_type
       ,COUNT(user_id) AS count
FROM (
       SELECT CASE type WHEN 'a' THEN 'A'
                        WHEN 'b' THEN 'B'
                        ELSE 'C'
                   END AS map_type
              ,user_id
       FROM user_types
     ) a
GROUP BY map_type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query (involving the sub-query) might be more performant. This is based on interpretation from Hive's explain plan, and running these queries a few times.

The explain plan for **query 1 (without the sub-query)** has this section:

```
Group By Operator [GBY_2]
                     aggregations:["count(user_id)"]
                     keys:CASE (type) WHEN ('a') THEN ('A') WHEN ('b') THEN ('B') ELSE ('C') END (type: string)
```

On the other hand, the same section for **query 2 (with the sub-query)** has this:

```
Group By Operator [GBY_3]
                     aggregations:["count(_col1)"]
                     keys:_col0 (type: string)
```

Based on the plan, it looks like query 2 is doing slightly less work.

Also ran a test on dummy data, and got these execution times.

```
Query 1: (1st time) 6.43 s, (2nd time) 5.92 s, (3rd time): 4.30s
Query 2: (1st time) 0.82 s, (2nd time) 1.29 s, (3rd time): 1.03s
```

Query 2 completed faster in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The expense of doing an aggregation involves reading lots and lots of data.  Then either sorting it or hashing it to bring the keys together.  Then the engine needs to process the data and calculate the count.

Whether a `case` expression is called once or twice is pretty meaningless in the context of all the data movement.  Don't worry about it.  If there is extra work, it is trivial compared to everything else that needs to be done for the query.

I also think that Hive supports column aliases in the `GROUP BY`, but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The case statement is not harmful in your case but if you are going to use a subquery that it might increase the time

you can continue with

```
SELECT CASE type WHEN 'a' THEN 'A'
                 WHEN 'b' THEN 'B'
                 ELSE 'C'
            END AS map_type
       ,COUNT(user_id) AS count
FROM user_types
GROUP BY CASE type WHEN 'a' THEN 'A'
                 WHEN 'b' THEN 'B'
                 ELSE 'C'
            END
;
```